# Best way to automate / implement a template engine for a static website?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a an collection of objects that I need to display on a website, each object is of the same class. The website has to: show the complete list of objects on the homepage, and have a dedicated page for each object.

What is the best way to implement this in JavaScript? I see 3 options:

1. Use JS custom elements to fill out necessary information.
2. Use a JS templating engine like Handlebars and import objects from separate js files.
3. Make an API / use Express JS to respond with a rendered HTML file. Also using a template engine, but without having to create HTML files for each object.

I am new to JS, so I may be missing some big things.

Comment: I believe react is best, but best is not a good option for greenhand, maybe vuejs or express with ejs suites you more

Comment: Best regarding performance would be Gatsby. Easiest would be express + pug/ejs.